# Cancel scheduled UILocalNotification if app is killed

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, kill

There will be a `UILocalNotification` scheduled in my app, but I found the scheduled `UILocalNotification` pops out even if I've killed the app. I don't think this is an expected behavior for my app. I am wondering if it is possible to cancel the scheduled `UILocalNotification` when user killed my app. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no - the documents on [app states and multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) are pretty clear that the method you'd use, [`-[UIApplicationDelegate applicationWillTerminate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a), is not called if your app is in the background.